# Recognize Dart as programming language

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

I noticed questions tagged with Dart are not automatically pretty-printed. For example, [Dart undefined is not a function when assigning final field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29218890).

**Explicitly** telling the editor to use `lang-dart` works. For example, [Symbol with private identifier argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29113434).

```
<!-- language: lang-dart -->

void main() { /* ... */ }
```

...but it doesn't happen automatically as with other languages.

I think the questions tagged with Dart would enjoy a cosmetic improvement if the language was colorized or pretty printed automatically rather than requiring folks to add `<!-- language: lang-dart -->`.

---

Apparently there's been [a request for this on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172966/add-default-syntax-highlighting-for-the-dart-tag) since March 2013.

---

*(Earlier I thought adding the explicit language thing didn't work, but that was apparently due to impatience.)*

Comment: [As far as I know](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) Stack Overflow already uses Google Code Prettify for syntax highlighting. According to the [Change Log of Google Code Prettify](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CHANGES.html)  it supports Dart since February 2013. I don't know if for some reason Stack Overflow is using an older version than that, but it seems that Dart syntax highlighting should work. At least in theory...

Comment: @Xaver Stack Exchange only pulls in a subset of what Prettify actually supports to keep the file size to a minimum.

Comment: Nice catch. Presumably just needs adding to a list somewhere, since the explicit thing works.

Comment: [MSE Request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172966/179419), been there for 2 years so far... (Potential MSE close-voters remember that other sites use Prettify).

Comment: \*Whistles\* there's nothing to see here, honest, @Stijn; degree in maths don't you know it couldn't possibly have been incorrect before your comment :-).

Comment: @animuson It’s a bit ludicrous that the world’s biggest general programming resource only supports a subset of languages for some silly size trade-off, don’t you think? The syntax highlighting on SO has always been a crutch. Okayish, but not great. Kind of sad.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I understand what you mean, but for people with very slow Internet (like me) it's nice if websites stay small and load faster.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It's perfectly reasonable not to include things that would barely ever get used. At the time the MSE request was made (March 2013), there were only about **800** Dart questions on Stack Overflow. Are you saying that it's more reasonable to include syntax checks that *every single user* has to download and use up more bandwidth to compensate for a very, very small portion of questions, which already get highlighted fairly decent by the default highlighter? Now that Dart has grown to near 5,000 questions, it's a bit more reasonable of a request.

Comment: @animuson What I’m saying is that I dislike the syntax highlighting on Stack Overflow fundamentally. Client-side syntax highlighting is a nice idea but it simply has tons of drawbacks, and it’s far from a robust solution. And relying on a decidedly brittle and sketchy solution with tons of trade-offs, rather than on a simple, robust solution — for one of the core aspects of the app! — is … weird.

Comment: @Kritzefitz That’s why you have content delivery networks and caching. So that stuff like this is transferred *once* and then never touched again (ideally).

Answer (score 5):

> **Explicitly** telling the editor to use lang-dart works.

Fun fact: it actually doesn't work. At least not the way you'd think. What happens is that Prettify tries to find the plugin that matches the language specification and falls back onto "default" if it fails to find one. Since we didn't have `lang-dart.js` anywhere, all that did was enable the default highlighter. Which, to be fair, didn't do that badly.

As of a bit ago, the Dart plugin has been installed and enabled on Stack Overflow for [dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dart).

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. The default colorizer did a really good job.